# Multi Executors Asynchronously to Write and Read Replies from TCP/IP Socket using Java

Tags: java, sockets, javafx, threadpoolexecutor, scheduledexecutorservice

This is my first time coding for the socket communication so you might see a beginner level's approach. Please bear with it.
I am trying to send and receive data from a device (devices in next step) through socket communication. the device receives commands and replies back in a second.
I am using 2 executors asynchronously. ***continuousCommandScheduler*** is to send commands after every 20 seconds and the other ***singleCommandScheduler*** is to send command after every one minute for limited no of times.

This code is for communication.
***CommunicationResult*** is just a class having getters and setters for finalData, outputData,outputLength and error.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.\*;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPortDataListener;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPortEvent;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPortIOException;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPortInvalidPortException;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPortTimeoutException;
import javafx.application.Platform; 

public class Communication {
     public static CompletableFuture<CommunicationResult> socketCommunication(Socket socket, String command)
                throws IOException {
            CompletableFuture<CommunicationResult> futureresult = new CompletableFuture<>();
            try {
                OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
                socket.setSoTimeout(2000);
    
                InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                output.write(command.getBytes());
                output.flush();
    
                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(); // Buffer for accumulating data
                boolean commandComplete = false; // Flag to indicate completion of a command.
    
                while (true) {
                    int character = read.read();
                    if (character == -1) {
                        futureresult.completeExceptionally(new SocketTimeoutException("Read timeout"));
                        break;
                    }
    
                    char ch = (char) character;
                    // Append new data if the command is not complete or if it's the start of a new command.
                    if (!commandComplete || ch == ':') {
                        buffer.append(ch);
                    }
    
                    // When "\r" is received, mark command as complete and process the data.
                    if (ch == '\r') {
                        String finalData = buffer.toString();
                        buffer.setLength(0);
                        CommunicationResult result = new CommunicationResult();
                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            result.setFinalData(finalData);
                            String outputData = Checksum.calculateReplyChecksum(finalData);
                            result.setOutputData(outputData);
                            String outputLength = Integer.toString(finalData.length());
                            result.setOutputLength(outputLength);
                            futureresult.complete(result);
                        });
                        commandComplete = true;
                        buffer.setLength(0); // Clear the buffer for the next command response
                        break;
                    }
                }
                socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
                buffer.setLength(0);
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException | UnknownHostException e) {
                handleSocketException(futureresult, e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                handleSocketException(futureresult, e);
            }
            return futureresult;
        }
      private static CommunicationResult createErrorResult(String errorMessage) {
            CommunicationResult result = new CommunicationResult();
            result.setError(errorMessage);
            return result;
        }
        private static void handleSocketException(CompletableFuture<CommunicationResult> future, Exception e) {
            CommunicationResult result = createErrorResult(e.getMessage());
            future.complete(result);
            ClassAlertMessages.showErrorDialogue("Error", "Exception occured: " + result.getError());
        }
    }
```

This is my GUI class which is designed for the user to able to connect with the device and send and receive data.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.text.*;

public class MainConnectionClass {
    //code to design GUI.
    ...
      btnConnect.setOnAction(event -> {
                handleSocketConnection();
            });
       btnSend.setOnAction(event -> {
    
                String inputValue = commandField.getText();
    
                String formattedChecksum = Checksum.calculateUIChecksum(inputValue);
                checksumField.setText(formattedChecksum);
                sendAndGetReply(inputValue).thenAccept(result -> {
                    String finalData = result.getFinalData();
                    String outputData = result.getOutputData();
                    String outputLength = result.getOutputLength();
                    String error = result.getError();
    
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        replyField.appendText(finalData + "\n");
                        outputchecksumField.setText(outputData);
                        lengthField.setText(outputLength);
                        errorLabel.setText(error);
                    });
                });
            });
     public void handleSocketConnection() {
            if (!isConnected) {
                connectSocket();
            } else {
                disconnectSocket();
            }
        }
    private void connectSocket() {
            hostName = hostNameField.getText();
            try {
                port = Integer.parseInt(portField.getText());
                socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostName, port), 5000);
                statusLabel.setText("Connected");
                statusLabel.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
                btnConnect.setText("Disconnect");
                isConnected = true;
                btnSend.setDisable(false);
                hostNameField.setDisable(true);
                portField.setDisable(true);
                comportPane.setDisable(true);
                instrumentPane.setDisable(true);
                textPane.setDisable(true);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                ClassAlertMessages.showErrorDialogue("Error",
                        "Invalid Hostname or Port. Please Enter a valid values. " + ex.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ClassAlertMessages.showErrorDialogue("Error", ex.getMessage() + "\nCheck your connection and Try again." );
            }
        }
    
        private void disconnectSocket() {
            if (socket != null && !socket.isClosed()) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                    isConnected = false;
                    btnConnect.setText("Connect");
                    statusLabel.setText("Not Connected");
                    statusLabel.setTextFill(Color.GRAY);
                    portField.setDisable(false);
                    btnSend.setDisable(true);
                    hostNameField.setDisable(false);
                    comportPane.setDisable(false);
                    instrumentPane.setDisable(false);
                    textPane.setDisable(false);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ClassAlertMessages.showErrorDialogue("Error", "Disconnection Error: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    public CompletableFuture<CommunicationResult> sendAndGetReply(String inputValue) {
    
            CompletableFuture<CommunicationResult> futureresult = new CompletableFuture<>();
     if (isConnected && !inputValue.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    if (socket != null && !socket.isClosed()) {
                        String formattedChecksum = Checksum.calculateUIChecksum(inputValue);
                        String wholeCommand = inputValue + formattedChecksum + "\r";
                        return Communication.socketCommunication(socket, wholeCommand);
                    }
                    else{
                        futureresult.completeExceptionally(new IOException("Socket is not open"));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    handleCommunicationException(futureresult, e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
            else {
                futureresult.completeExceptionally(new IOException("Connection Problem"));
            }
            return futureresult;
        }
    }
```

So I am registering the instruments/devices through my MainConnection GUI class and then from this class, through button clicks I am Running both my executors.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
    
public class StageTables {
      private ScheduledExecutorService singleCommandScheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        private ScheduledExecutorService continuousCommandScheduler;
    
    private MainConnectionClass mainApp = new MainConnectionClass();
     public StageTables(MainConnectionClass mainApp) {
            this.mainApp = mainApp;
            continuousCommandScheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(0);
        }
    btnStartSampling.setOnAction(event -> {
    
                if (!registeredInstruments.isEmpty()) {
                    CompletableFuture<Void> multipleFuture = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> sendMultipleCommands());
                    multipleFuture.thenRun(() -> {
                        singleCommandScheduler("10178", 10, 1);
                        System.out.println("Command Function Executed... ");
                    });
                } else {
                    ClassAlertMessages.showWarningMessage(null, "Warning",
                            "Either no instrumenst is registered to start sampling.");
                }
            });
     btnStopSampling.setOnAction(event -> {
    
                if (singleCommandScheduler != null && !registeredInstruments.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println(singleCommandScheduler);
                    sendCommands("6");
                    System.out.println("Stop Sampling");
                    shutdownSingleCommandScheduler();
                } else {
                    ClassAlertMessages.showWarningMessage(null, "Warning",
                            "Either no instruments is registered or Sampling is not running");
                }
            });
    
            btnShowTables.setOnAction(event -> {
                createTabs();
                startSendingCommands();
            });
    
     public void startSendingCommands() {
            try {
                continuousCommandScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::continuousCommandSender, 0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.severe("Exception occured while sending command (4): " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    
        private void continuousCommandSender() {
            commands = new String[] { "F", "E" };
            int delay = 0;
            for (String command : commands) {
                String inputValue = registeredInstruments.get(0) + command;
                continuousCommandScheduler.schedule(() -> continuousCommandScheduler(inputValue, command), delay,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                delay += 5;
            }
        }
     private void continuousCommandScheduler(String inputValue, String command) {
            try {
                CompletableFuture<CommunicationResult> commandReplies = mainApp.sendAndGetReply(inputValue);
                System.out.println("\nInput Value (ContSender): " + inputValue);
                commandReplies.whenCompleteAsync((result, throwable) -> {
                    if (throwable != null) {
                        LOGGER.severe("Error occured while sending continuous command: " + throwable.getMessage());
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                        ClassAlertMessages.showErrorDialogue("Error Occured",
                                "Unable to send command: " + throwable.getMessage());
                    } else {
                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            try {
                                finalData = result.getFinalData();
                                if (finalData != null) {
                                    if (Validations.isDataValid(finalData, inputValue.substring(1)) == true) {
                                        if (finalData.length() == 46) {
                                            System.out.println("REPLY for F (ContSender): " + finalData);
                                        } else if (finalData.length() == 26) {
                                            System.out.println("REPLY for E (ContSender): " + finalData);
                                        } else {
                                            System.out.println("Invalid reply (ContSender): " + finalData);
                                            System.out.println("\nNot Valid Data");
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("\nNull Data");
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                LOGGER.severe(
                                        "Error occured while processing continuous command result: " + e.getMessage());
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.severe("Error occured while sending continuous command: " + e.getMessage());
                ClassAlertMessages.showErrorDialogue("Exception Occured", "Unable to send command: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
       private void sendMultipleCommands() {
            String value = "801A501" + setStorageIntervalValue.getText();
            String[] commands = { value, "701A5", "4" };
            CompletableFuture<Void> previousCommand = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
            for (String command : commands)
                previousCommand = previousCommand.thenRunAsync(() -> {
                    try {
                        sendCommands(command);
                        Thread.sleep(1500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        LOGGER.severe("Interupted while sending command (1): " + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
        }
      private void singleCommandScheduler(String command, int repeatCount, long intervalTime) {
    
            String inputValue = registeredInstruments.get(0) + command;
            AtomicInteger commandCounter = new AtomicInteger(repeatCount);
            Runnable commandSender = () -> {
                if (commandCounter.get() > 0 && !singleCommandScheduler.isTerminated()) {
                    CompletableFuture<CommunicationResult> commandReplies = mainApp.sendAndGetReply(inputValue);
                    System.out.println("\nInput Value (Repeated Single): " + inputValue);
                    commandReplies.whenComplete((result, throwable) -> {
                        if (throwable != null) {
                            throwable.printStackTrace();
                        } else {
                            try {
                                finalData = result.getFinalData();
                                System.out.println("\nRepeated Data Output: " + finalData);
                                if (finalData != null) {
                                    if (Validations.samplingDataValidation(finalData, inputValue.substring(1)) == true) {
                                        if (finalData.length() == 78) {
                                            System.out.println("Valid Data");
                                            gettingTableValues(finalData);
                                            commandCounter.decrementAndGet();
                                        } else {
                                            System.err.println("Invalid data");
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("Null Data");
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                LOGGER.severe("Error occured while sending command (2): " + e.getMessage());
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    singleCommandScheduler.shutdown();
                    sendCommands("6");
                    System.out.println("Sampling done");
                }
            };
    
            singleCommandScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(commandSender, 0, intervalTime, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
    }
```

This above whole code is working fine as in other class I am using thread to get the values for creating a document but the problem I am encountering is when I run executors.

This happens when there is a read time out exception. I started getting the result of previous command

```
Input Value (ContSender): !O0265E
REPLY for E (ContSender): :O0265E030001014F00014024

Input Value (ContSender): !O0265F
REPLY for F (ContSender): :O0265F0401000B03E77A95420001002400104D0F0F6E

Input Value (ContSender): !O0265E

Null Data

Input Value (ContSender): !O0265F
REPLY for E (ContSender): :O0265E030001014F00020021

Input Value (ContSender): !O0265E
REPLY for F (ContSender): :O0265F0401000B03E77A95460001002400104D0F0F72
```

This is the result when both executors and a thread are running.

```
Input Value (ContSender): !O0265F
REPLY for F (ContSender): :O0265F04010013044479994000018E2400104D0F0F64

Input Value (ContSender): !O0265E
REPLY for E (ContSender): :O0265E040001010100364115

Input Value (Repeated Single): !O026510178

Repeated Data Output: null
Null Data

Input Value (ContSender): !O0265F
Invalid reply (ContSender): :O026510178016C01460200015A00000000000000000161013A01F7015400000000000001635D

Not Valid Data

Input Value (Repeated Single): !O026510178

Repeated Data Output: :O026510178016B013F020A016500000000000000000162013A01F90156000000000000016376
Valid Data

Input Value (ContSender): !O0265F
REPLY for F (ContSender): :O0265F040100160450799A4400018E2400104D0F0F70

Input Value (ContSender): !O0265E

Null Data

Input Value (ContSender): !O0265F
REPLY for E (ContSender): :O0265E04000101010040010C

Input Value (ContSender): !O0265E
REPLY for F (ContSender): :O0265F040100170454799A4000018E2400104D0F0F71

Input Value (ContSender): !O0265F
REPLY for E (ContSender): :O0265E04000101010040210E

Input Value (ContSender): !O0265E
REPLY for F (ContSender): :O0265F040100170454799A4400018E2400104D0F0F75
```

This is the result I want. Means if any data is miss or null, or whatever, the buffer must be at length 0 before receiving the next command. I am getting this result through comport communication using JSerialComm library. Everything else is same for that. just the communication code is different.

```
Input Value (ContSender): !O4101F
REPLY for F (ContSender): :O4101F280106F30F1B7A9842400100240040276F0F8C

Counter: 10
Command Function Executed...

SENT: !O4101801A50101

Input Value (Repeated Single): !O410110178
REPLY (sendCommnads): :O4101801A5010199

SENT: !O4101701A5
REPLY (sendCommnads): :O4101701A5010199

Input Value (ContSender): !O4101E
REPLY for E (ContSender): :O4101E27240304FF12074252

SENT: !O41014
REPLY (sendCommnads): :O41014280106F30F1B7A9844400130240040276F0F91

Input Value (Repeated Single): !O410110178

Repeated Data Output: :O4101101780000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000D0
Valid Data

Counter: 9

Input Value (ContSender): !O4101E
REPLY for E (ContSender): :O4101E272403040112084228

Input Value (ContSender): !O4101F

Not Valid Data

Input Value (ContSender): !O4101E
REPLY for E (ContSender): :O4101E282403040112090226

Input Value (ContSender): !O4101F
REPLY for F (ContSender): :O4101F280106F50F6079994240318E240040276F0F9A
```

Please guide me how can I solve this issue.
I tried everything I can find to solve it but I am stuck now. Unable to crack this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Don't post images of text. Post the output as text, formatted as code.

Comment: @James_D updated that.